# Load initial data in an angularjs app

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm currently trying to develop an AngularJS app. This is my first application using AngularJS and I think I'm pretty aware of how it works since I've been a Silverlight developer for some years :-)

However, there's one, simple thing I cannot figure out: how to get the initial data for the app when it starts.

What I need is a simple table of data where a few fields can be edited inline (by dropdowns) My app structure is like this:

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('feedbackApp', []);
```

**feedbackService.js**

```
app.service('feedbackService', function ($http) {
this.getFeedbackPaged = function (nodeId, pageNumber, take) {
    $http.get('myUrl', function (response) {
        return response;
    });
};
});
```

**feedbackController.js**

```
app.controller('feedbackController', function ($scope, feedbackService, $filter) {
// Constructor for this controller
init();

function init() {
    $scope.feedbackItems = feedbackService.getFeedbackPaged(1234, 1, 20);
}
});
```

**Markup**

```
<html ng-app="feedbackApp">
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="table" style="border: 1px solid #000; width:50%;">
        <tr ng-repeat="fb in feedbackItems | orderBy: 'Id'" style="width:auto !important;">
            <td data-title="Ansvarlig">
                {{ fb.Name }}
            </td>
            <td data-title="Kommentar">
                {{ fb.Comment }}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

But the table is empty when I run the application. I think it's because the app starts before the data from the service is added to the viewmodel ($scope), but I have no idea of how to make it initialise before the app starts, so the first 20 table rows are displayed.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's an `ng-init` directive, might be worth looking at. Is the table eventually getting populated or always blank?

Comment: hi tymeJV, thanks - i'll have a look at that :-) The table is always blank, unfortunately.

Comment: Ahh, seems your service is a bit messed up, see the answer below, have to carry that `promise` over!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should modify your code a bit to make it working since you are working with promise here you should use .then

```
app.service('feedbackService', function ($http) {
this.getFeedbackPaged = function (nodeId, pageNumber, take) {
    return $http.get('myUrl');
};
});

app.controller('feedbackController', function ($scope, feedbackService, $filter) {
// Constructor for this controller
init();

function init() {
   feedbackService.getFeedbackPaged(1234, 1, 20).then(function(data){$scope.feedbackItems=data;});
}
});
```

Comment: Ajay, you Sir did just save me from pulling my hair all night! It works like a charm. Thank you so much!! :-)

Comment: I think the init() method is redundant. It should work without making it as a init method like, app.controller('feedbackController', function ($scope, feedbackService, $filter) { feedbackService.getFeedbackPaged(1234, 1, 20).then(function(data){$scope.feedbackItems=data;});
});